# What function to I need to plot in MATLAB to get the reflection of this graph?

Tags: matlab, graph

I have confused myself slightly. I have plotted 1 - 0.95^(x) in MATLAB and got this graph.[image]

However I want the reflection of this about '50' on the x axis whereby I can get a near 1 penalty for low x values and then the penalty starts to decrease as x increases.
Does anyone have any suggestions on the function I would need for this I appear to be having a mind blank!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this? Just cut the "1-".

[image: y=a^x]

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I did try that but I wanted it to go along reading a value of 1 for a while, for example for the first x = 1:40, have it as y = 1.

Comment: You could just concatenate ones and your expression like:
`[ones(1,40) 0.95.^(1:100)]`

Comment: @emilysusan would you mind accepting this as an answer if it answers your question? Or otherwise specify the question perhaps. Thanks :)